# OpenStack Live-Migration VNC server error

Tags: kvm-virtualization, vnc, libvirt, openstack, live-migration

Following [these steps](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/tutorial-openstack-live-migration-with-kvm-hypervisor-and-nfs-shared-storage/) to do a live migration results in:

```
2014-12-08 00:42:38.772 17808 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-] 
[instance: db9d53ac-4a75-4009-a67e-f45abf9d4d32] Live Migration failure: internal error: 
early end of file from monitor: possible problem:
qemu-system-x86_64: Failed to start VNC server on `10.84.1.8:1': Failed to bind socket: 
Cannot assign requested address
```

Any ideas?

Comment: nova is calling libvirt is some way or another, try to live migrate an instance using `virsh` first

Comment: Does the destination host have the 10.84.1.8 IP assigned?